# Sqlite Query Optimization with OR and AND

Tags: sqlite, nhibernate

The following query takes 5 seconds to execute:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(Product.Name) FROM Product WHERE (0=1 OR Product.Number="prod11");
```

While the following takes ONLY 15 milliseconds:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(Product.Name) FROM Product WHERE (Product.Number="prod11");
```

Interestingly the following also takes only 15 milliseconds:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(Product.Name) FROM Product WHERE (1=1 AND Product.Number="prod11");
```

The query plan shows that the first query uses a full table scan (for some unknown reason), while the second and third queries use an index (as expected).

For some reason it looks like Sqlite optimizes the "1=1 AND ..." but it doesn't optimize "0=1 OR ...".

What can I do to make Sqlite use the index for the first query as well?

The queries are built by NHibernate so it's kind of hard to change them...

Sqlite version is the latest for Windows.

Comment: 0_o Is there a reason why you have the superfluous statements in the `where` conditions (ie `0=1` and `1=1`)?

Comment: Well this is only a simplified part of a bigger query. The 0=1 and 1=1 checks are used to enable or disable parts of the WHERE clause depending on the search criteria. On the NHibernate side the query contains something like (!criteria.FilterByProductNumber || criteria.ProductNumber == product.Number) && (!criteria.FilterByOtherProperty || criteria.OtherProperty = product.OtherProperty).. the "!criteria.FilterBy..." causes the constant 0=1 and 1=1 expressions to be inserted.

Comment: Postgres actually also optimizes the 0=1 case to use an index. I see no reason why Sqlite could optimize 1=1 but not 0=1...?

Comment: Have you tried removing the unnecessary statements?

Comment: I can't remove them.. NHibernate creates them.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite's query optimizer is rather simple and [does not support `OR` expressions very well](http://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html#or_in_where).

For some reason, it *can* optimize this query if it can use a *covering* index, so try this:

```
CREATE INDEX TakeThatNHibernate ON Product(Number, Name)
```

Answer (score 0):

`1=1`and `1=0` are SQL expressions used in some parts of the `NHibernate` framework to denote empty statements that won't alter the logic of the sql query. A `Conjunction` with no subcriterias generates an `1=1` expression, A `Disjunction` with no subcriterias generates an `1=0` expression. An In() generates an `1=0` expression if no values are provided.

To avoid such optimization, you could change the code that is creating those empty expressions and only use the criterions that have at least one subcriteria.